# Forcing ignore Children css

Tags: css

I have this case:

firstCSSPage.css

```
.wrong-parent{
   font-size: 10px;
}

.wrong-child{
   font-size: 5px;
}
```

secondCSSPage.css

```
.parent {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

.html

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="wrong-parent">
      <span class="wrong-child">
         Text test target.
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="wrong-parent">
      <span class="wrong-child">
         Text test target seconde.
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can't change the .html and firstCSSPage.css 
Can I find a way to force all text in the spans to ignore the wrong-parent and wrong-child css ?

Comment: `.parent > div.wrong-parent > span.wrong-child { font-size: 20px; }` ?

Comment: Add more specific selector than in `firstCSSPage.css` and you good to go

Comment: You misspelled child: `<span class="wrong-chidl">`

Comment: @RolandoYera
example corrected

Comment: @Justinas : 
I can't modify firstCSSPage.css the .html,  only secondCSSPage.css

Comment: @alexalias Yes, so in second page add `.parent .wrong-parent {font-size: 20px}`

Answer (score -2):

Rewrite Same class in secondCSSPage.css

`.wrong-parent{ font-size: unset !important; }`

`.wrong-child{ font-size: unset !important; }`

Comment: The `!important` keyword should be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/